# how to print out the user number input with the result instead of showing only result?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input, println

I am trying to print out the numbers that user input but i got no idea (example: when user input 2 and 3, it should be show 2+3=5 instead of 5 alone ) also how to find the average of the number too.
here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your first number: ");
    int firstnumber= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");
    int secondnumber= keyboard.nextInt();
    int sum= firstnumber+secondnumber;
    System.out.println(sum);
    int minus= firstnumber-secondnumber;
    System.out.println(minus);
    int multiply= firstnumber*secondnumber;
    System.out.println(multiply);
    int divide= firstnumber/secondnumber;
    System.out.println(divide);
    int moddivide= firstnumber%secondnumber;
    System.out.println(moddivide);
    **int average= sum/2;**
    System.out.println(average);

    keyboard.close();


}
```

}

as you can see at (star)(star).....(star)(star) it shouldn't be /2 because it doesn't look like a professional at all...

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed. I don't see how this question has anything to do with Javascript.

Comment: The average of two integers is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: @hovercraft ops! sorry, i'm new with this stuff

Comment: @PM 77-1 that what i said how can i find the average without using number 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use formated output here:

```
System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d\n",firstnumber,secondnumber,sum);//<-- prints `3 + 4 = 7`
```

Formats:

```
%d, integers
%s, string
%b, boolean
%f, floating
```

To compute average in decimals:

```
double average = sum / 2.0;
System.out.printf("Avg of %d & %d = %f\n",firstnumber,secondnumber,average);
```

Comment: @bscouth, kindly accept the answer, as it worked for you

Comment: @bscouth Please accept this if it has worked for you. Many questions are missing "best answers" due to people forgetting/not caring for choose one. This is NOT how stackoverflow is meant to wrom (you got your answer, screw everyone else). Let the community know you found an answer and that it was helpful

Comment: @Arvind  wheww yes it's all working just want to mention it's okay for me to use int instead of double because the user doesn't require the real number (with dash small point) in the result

Comment: @Arvind [Formatted](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/formated) is with double 't' (unless you are talking about flying aircraft in a formation); I corrected but you edited it back.

Comment: Hi, I wonder why i get error when i run this code: 
int moddivide= firstnumber % secondnumber;
System.out.printf("%d % %d = %d/n", firstnumber, secondnumber, moddivide);
Thank

Comment: @bscouth, since your using formatted output, `%` has special meaning, try this `%%` instead also its `\n` not `/n` System.out.printf("%d %% %d = %d\n", firstnumber, secondnumber, moddivide);

Comment: ah ha!! work like a charm!! thank again Arvind, you're awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

This is code you are looking for:

```
System.out.println(firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + sum);
```

Code for average:

```
double average = (double) sum / 2;
System.out.println(average);
```

Comment: No problem. You only will have problem with option average because it won't always be Integer. Use the code I added for it.

Comment: ummm for real number (double) and integer is okay but the point is: what if there is more than 2 inputs like it cannot be count so what to do?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you be more specific please? Or just give me code.

Comment: ummmm what i really mean is:  is there any way to get average without divide by 2?

Answer (score 0):

It basicly means that you have not had a quatation mark some where so the computer dose not know where the end of your sentence is .(or start)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31585703)

Answer (score 0):

Write your code below this line 
print("Day 1 - Python Print Function")
print(The function is declared like this:)
print("print('what to print')") .  Can you see where you put the  qutation mark?